# indexing/linking rows to a unique identifier

Tags: r, function, indexing, unique

My data:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
start<-c(0,1,3,5,7,8,10,0,0,1)
end<-c(1,3,5,7,8,9,12,0,1,4)
mydata<-data.frame(id,start,end)
```

Question:

What code would I use to indicate that rows 1-7 are linked to the unique `id(1)`, and rows 8-10 are linked to `id(2)`? The output should look as follows:

```
Indexes[1:2]
$ '1'
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
$ '2'
8 9 10`
```

Attempt:

I have looked around StackOverflow but don't really see this being done. I did try

```
split(mydata,mydata$id)
```

I know that if I say:

```
which(mydata$id==1)
```

It will tell me rows 1-7. But don't know how to use this to my advantage to get the output above.

but that certainly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.  `split` can be used on the `rownames` as well. Since they'll be character values, you coerce them to numeric with `as.numeric`

```
> Indexes <- split(as.numeric(rownames(mydata)), mydata$id)
> Indexes[1:2]   ## or just 'Indexes' for your sample data
## $`1`
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

## $`2`
## [1]  8  9 10
```